# Can't connect to oracle database with Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, listener, oracle18c, tnsnames

When I try to connect I get error:

[image]

I disabled firewall, started the OracleServiceXE, but still get error.

When I use command lsnrctl status, I get:

[image]

lsnrctl start:

[image]

My tnsnames.ora file looks like that:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\Coi\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.8)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
```

Comment: looks like your database isn't up and running...listener log can't service the database because the db you're describing...doesn't exist

Comment: as if the service needs to be registered.

Comment: Lets see your listener.ora.  If this is all running on your own machine, it might be the case that DHCP has given you a new IP address. It might be easier to edit listener.ora to have it listen on localhost rather than an IP address.  Then adjust your tnsnames.ora accordingly.